# Problems with lmfit's Model object's attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use lmfit to curve fit data to a model, but whenever I try to do anything with the params attributes of the model (such as set values for the parameters) it tells me it can't find them.
My program's long and has a fair amount of stuff going on, so I tried running the example, doc_model1.py, which can be found here http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/model.html

```
#doc_model1.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#<examples/doc_model1.py>
from numpy import sqrt, pi, exp, linspace, loadtxt
from lmfit import  Model

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = loadtxt('model1d_gauss.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    "1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)"
    return (amp/(sqrt(2*pi)*wid)) * exp(-(x-cen)**2 /(2*wid**2))
gmod = Model(gaussian)
result = gmod.fit(y, x=x, amp=5, cen=5, wid=1)

print(gmod.fit_report())
...
```

IDLE didn't object to anything that program tried to do, but when I tried to do anything with parameters after that, such as

```
for name, par in gmod.params.items():
    print(name, par)
```

or

```
gmod.params[’amp’].value = 10.0
```

(which are both copied straight from the documentation) I got

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'params'
```

Similarly, any time I try to do anything with set_params it says that Model doesn't have that attribute either. All the other attributes of Model seem to work fine, why not the parameter ones?
I'm using Python2.7 on a computer running Windows7

Comment: I just tried using pip to uninstall and reinstall lmfit (I'm not even sure I'm doing that right. I opened up Powershell, changed the directory to Python27/Scripts and used ./pip uninstall lmfit and ./pip install lmfit) and it said "warning: no files found matching 'README.txt'" and "warning: no previously-included files found matching" '*.pyc', 'core.*', '*~', '*.pdf', '*.dat' under directory 'tests', '*' found under directory 'doc\_build', '*.pdf' found under directory 'doc' twice. When I try to run the code above, I get a string of errors, mostly dealing with deepcopy...

Comment: uninstalled with pip in Powershell, reinstalled by using setup.py install with windows command line. CMD gave same complaints, but now the program runs, but still not knowing what params is.